# Using docker-compose to build one of many dockerfiles in a repository

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

We can build a Dockerfile directly from the [root of a git repository](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#git-repositories), e.g.

```
$ docker build https://github.com/docker/rootfs.git#container:docker
```

This takes a dockerfile located at the root of the git repository and uses the root as build context.

However, sometimes there are multiple docker files for one repository, for example [the onedrive linux client](https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/tree/master/contrib/docker) there are 5 dockerfiles and I want to build a specific file.

What is the correct way to do this in a docker-compose file? My setup currently looks as follows

```
services:
  onedrive:
    image: local-onedrive
    # I want to build the following file: 
    # https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/contrib/docker/Dockerfile-rpi
    build: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive.git#
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - ONEDRIVE_UID=${PUID}
      - ONEDRIVE_GID=${PGID}
    volumes: 
      - ${CONFIG_DIR}/onedrive:/onedrive/conf
      - ${ONEDRIVE_DIR}:/onedrive/data
```

A main advantage would be that updating would be directly done from the author's repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docker documentation link you reference says:

> When the `URL` parameter points to the location of a Git repository, the repository acts as the build context.

You should be able to use the `docker build -f` option or the Compose [`dockerfile:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dockerfile) setting to specify an alternate Dockerfile, within that context directory.

```yaml
build:
  context: 'https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive.git#'
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-alpine
```

Comment: The context portion should not contain a #, as this is used for changing the build context. the dockerfile is then relative to the path in the repo, in this case 'contrib/docker/Dockerfile-rpi'. Thanks! I will mark your solution as right.